# High-end components

Tags: mountain-bike, brakes, crankset, parts, fixed-gear

I'm wondering if anyone knows of any high-end components that are like Paul components. Not the pro-peloton stuff like SRAM and Shimano, but the, dare I say hipster components.

I'm looking for components for a fixie and a vintage mountain bike (both cantilever and vbrakes, and the center bolt brakes, triple cranks, single cranks wheels, stems,  everything!)

I really like the vintage anodized aluminum look.

Comment: I never realised mountain bikes had been around long enough to have passed from "old" to "vintage" :-P

Comment: @Criggie they've been round a lot longer than many of the kids riding them. I suspect there are kids riding now whose parents were born after the fad started. By the time I got my first MTB in about 1985 you could buy BSO-grade "mountain bikes"

Comment: @Mσᶎ I sure know that my bike has a good nine years on me! And I'm only 17 so that would fit the picture your painting haha!

Comment: You are 17?  How much money do you have to burn?   These hipster components are going to cost  a LOT of money and not perform better than current pro-peloton.  And this *vintage* bike is not  going to be worth the price of the hipster components.  Could you learn to like a modern titanium look?

Comment: @Frisbee - do you know what bicycle the OP is talking about? How do you know what it might be worth?

Comment: @JHCL Do you know what is worth?  Do you know a single *vintage*  bike with expensive non-original components worth more than the components.      Cantilever or vbrake is not *vintage* .

Comment: Err, no, but that's not what you said. If the OP has a 1989 Ritchey SuperComp that he found in a shed, you could throw an awful lot of sexy anodised stuff at it and still be ahead, money-wise (if that's what you're interested in).

Comment: not sure what you're looking for but maybe check out rivbike.com and velo-orange.com.

Comment: @JHCL *Still* be money ahead is not money ahead in my book.   If that 1989 Ritchey SuperComp had original components bet it would have been worth more if they were left on.

Answer (score 5):

Cook Bros, Chris King, Tune and Middleburn spring to mind, but in the 90s there were plenty of 'boutique' and exotic component makers.
Have you had a look at [**retrobike.co.uk**](http://www.retrobike.co.uk)?

(Edit to add: Ringlé, Grafton, Control Tech, Syncros... but there are more.)

Comment: Add Tomac, Bontrager... looks like every famous MTB rider at the time had a component brand named after them...

Answer (score 0):

There is a company called [Velo Orange](http://velo-orange.com/) that sells stuff of the type you seek. They have other brands as well as house brands.

Note that I've no personal interest in this company not have I ever purchased anything from them. However I have a few friends who've been very happy customers, and the stuff they've purchased has looked to be of high quality.

Comment: Commercial links are fine. You have already declared that you have no connection to the company. A plain link is OK, but try to make the link work in a more durable way, for example by linking to the company home page or search page, or via Google.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification on commercial links.  I've edited the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the sweet compoents from Paul Components, White Industries, Chris King. You'll find fancy machined cranks, hubs, freewheels that are built to last and look sweet. Chris king thrown in for badass headsets and bottom brackets that last.